# I want to write a letter in Hindi

Tags: languages, letters

I want to write a letter in Hindi. I want to use mikTeX to create the PDF document in Hindi. I don't want to have transliteration from English to Hindi. How can I do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you have a Hindi font in OpenType or TrueType formats (usually with an `.otf` or `.ttf` extension), it should be pretty easy using the LuaTeX or XeTeX engines (compiling with `lualatex` or `xelatex`).

Answer (score 1):

run with `xelatex` or `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial Unicode MS}
\begin{document}
कुछ पाठ उम्मीद है, हिंदी में लिखा.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can write using `\usepackage{devnagari}` and use command `\dn` to write things in hindi.
Make a file with `.dn` extension
go to the directory in terminal or cmd (or powershell). run command `devnag filename.dn` and you will get a filename.tex file. Compile it as you compile your tex files.
 for example:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\def\DevnagVersion{2.15}
\usepackage{devanagari}
\begin{document}
@modernhindi
{\dn{\dnveda sahI-galata, kucha hai bhI aura nahIM bhI hai|
samajha meM nahIM aa rahaa hai| vaise jo kucha hai, vaha saba galata hai aura usa saba meM svayaM maiM bhI huu/|
hara tarafa se eka hI aavaaza sunaaI detI hai mujhe-maiM galata huu/|
lekina maiM kahaa/ se galata huu/, kyoM galata huu/ in pra"snoM kaa uttara maiM nahIM de sakataa aura maiM soca rahaa huu/ kyaa kahIM
koI uttara hai bhI?
}}


@modernhindi
{\dn
{\dnveda
pra"sna hI pra"sna! pratyeka uttara svayaM meM eka pra"sna hai| ina pra"snoM me hI to samasta utsukataa hai,
samasta kautuuhala hai aura yahI kautuuhala tathaa utsuktaa jIvana kI prera.naa hai| jo uttara hai vaha mara cukaa hai, vaha vigata hai| jo pra"sna hai usI meM hamaarI sthaapanaa hai, vahI ad.r"sya aur aj~naata hai, usI kI upalabdhi meM amaratva hai| jis samay pra"snoM ka a.mta ho jaataa hai usI samaya jIvana kaa bhI a.mta ho jaataa hai aura maiM abhI jIvit hU/, isalie pra"snoM se ladaa huaa maiM svayaM apane lie ek pra"sna ban cukaa huu/| 
}}

{\dn bhagavatIcara.n varmaa}


{\dn pra"sna aur marIcikaa}

\end{document}
```

after running `devnag` command you will get a tex file.